# Condition == null and != null returns the same row

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I make some joins to access the field `IsVacancyActive`.

When I write condition `s.IsVacancyActive == null`, I'm getting several rows and there is one which shouldn't be there.

And still if I write `s.IsVacancyActive != null`, then I'm geting another collection of rows, including that one row, which I have in the previous condition. How can it be? How it can have both values `null` and `not null`?

P.S. I use `into` for the left join

```
var data = (from c in db.Table1
            join cm in db.Table2 on c.CandidateId equals cm.CandidateId into var1 from cm in var1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join lp in db.Table3 on c.KotelPositionId equals lp.PositionId into var2 from lp in var2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join pg in db.Table4 on lp.PositionId equals pg.PositionId into var3 from pg in var3.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join lpt in db.Table5 on pg.LinkPositionGradeId equals lpt.LinkPositionGradeId into var4 from lpt in var4.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join s in db.Table6 on lpt.LinkPositionTeamId equals s.LinkPositionTeamId into var5 from s in var5.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join cv in db.Table7 on s.StaffId equals cv.VacancyId into var6 from cv in var6.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join cvac in db.Table8 on c.CandidateId equals cvac.CandidateId into var7 from cvac in var7.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where s.IsVacancyActive == null// Error
            select new
            {
                c
            }).Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Hint:  `IS NULL`.  `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: It's better to use `s.IsVacancyActive is null`. But this depends on the compatibility vector activated in SQL Server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is Linq query language, there is no `is null` or `is not null`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question since you didn't post anything useful to track down your issue, you absolutely don't need to do `new { c }`, just return `c` if that's what you want. And I hope it isn't, because returning the result of that monstrosity will choke your network and kill the garbage collector.

Comment: With `is null` it give me an error  "An expression tree may not contain an 'is' pattern-matching operator."

Comment: I'm not sure how you're able to use the same variable names for the joins and the `DefaultIfEmpty` left joins, I'd recommend using different variable names and make sure you check the one from the `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: @Blindy Since those are all joins instead of Includes the result will just be the entities from `Table1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the LINQ query in the question ultimately resolves to a SQL database transaction, then the where clause:

```
where s.IsVacancyActive == null// Error
```

...may be parsed by LINQ to a null comparison in SQL, i.e. as X = NULL or X != NULL, which are both false in SQL.

Try:

```
where s.IsVacancyActive.HasValue
```